# how do I remove border and effects from WPF repeatbutton when an imagebrush is used as the background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, repeatbutton

I am working with a repeatbutton object in WPF, the button needs to be graphic based (Image brush background and no border or other superfluous effects).

The problem I have is that no matter what i try there is still a white rectangle around the button, and, i am not sure now after looking at this for a few hours that I am sure I understand why or how to remove it.

I have created the button using the following in the XAML

```
 <RepeatButton Content="" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="334,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="149" Height="100" Background="{DynamicResource ImageBrush_Decrement}" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonStyle_noflash}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
```

You will note that I am referencing a style of "RepeatButtonNoFlash" which i used to remove the defaultrender (as it was causing a flashing effect, this style is defined in a shared dictionary as below

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="0" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->

    <Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="False" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonChromeStyle_noborder}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RepeatButtonStyle_noflash" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

regards

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's coming from the `Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome` try replacing that with a border or something, should get rid of it.

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: The template that Blend created for you has the line <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome. This is what's drawing that white border you can see. if you look at the code I've posted I've removed that ButtonChrome and replaced it with a simple border. I've also had to remove some Triggers from the collection below that referenced the chrome border by name.

Comment: Thanks, I have only just got near a PC where I can test this and it works perfectly ... thank you so much